# Python XML parsing with ElementTree: findall retuns empty list

Tags: python, xml

My XML begins like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="define2-0-0.xsl"?>
<ODM
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3"
  xmlns:def="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/def/v2.0"
  xmlns:nciodm="http://ncicb.nci.nih.gov/xml/odm/EVS/CDISC"
  ODMVersion="1.3.2"
  FileType="Snapshot"
  FileOID="SDTM-Terminology-2015-06-26.odm.xml.."
  CreationDateTime="2016-08-30T16:37:21">
    <Study OID="SDTM-Terminology-2015-06-26.odm.xml..">
    ...it goes on from there
```

I can parse it into am ELementTree object:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = tree.getroot()
```

This code:

```
for child in root:
    print "Child of root:  " + child.tag
```

Produces:

```
Child of root:  {<some url>}Study
```

I need to traverse several levels down the tree, and I don't want to have to use 7-8 nested "for child in..." loops.  I want to use XMLPath but I can't get anything to work.  This code:

```
for node in tree.findall('./Study')
    print(node.tag)
```

returns nothing.  I can't get it to return anything.  I've tried

```
for node in root.findall('./Study')
    print (node.tag)
```

and it also produces nothing.  I've tried all kinds of combinations of root & tree, with and without the leading "./".  I can't get anything to work.  This is my first time working with ElementTree; can someone help me?

Comment: `namespaces = {'odm': 'http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3'}` then  `tree.findall('.//odm:Study', namespaces)`.  See duplicate link for further info.

Comment: ...and, please, accept some of helpful answers to the questions you've asked.  Thanks.